# Using plain Servlets (no Spring) and retrofit, how do I engage in 2 way client-server communication?

Tags: java, servlets, retrofit

The retrofit interface is shown below. I'd like to return an integer for the acquire method, but the Servlet's get and Post methods are both void. How can I receive this integer after the Servlet does its work? I want the methods to be executed synchronously, so I don't think Callbacks are an option.

```
    /**
 * The path where the Palintiri Service is expected to live.
 */
public static final String PALINTIRI_SVC_PATH =
    "/Palantiri";

/**
 * Gets the id of a Palintir from the Palintiri Service.
 *
 * @return Unique id that the client will use in subsequent
 *         requests for gazing and releasing the Palintir.
   */ 
@GET(PALINTIRI_SVC_PATH)
int acquire(@Query("leaseDuration") long leaseDuration);

/**
 * Gazes at the Palintir for a random period of time specified by
 * the Server.
 *
 * @param id 
 *        The Unique id used to identify the Palantir.
 * @return Response (200 if successful and 
 * remaining time <= 0, otherwise if successful, 201).
 */
@GET(PALINTIRI_SVC_PATH)
Response gaze(@Query("id") long id);

/**
 * Releases the Palintir.
 *
 * @param id
 *        The id used to identify a Palantir uniquely.
 * @return Response (200 if successful).
 */
@POST(PALINTIRI_SVC_PATH)
Response release(@Query("id") long id);

/**
 * Makes Palintiri 
 * @param numberOfPalintiri 
 *      the number of Palintiri that need to be created
 * 
 * @return Response (200 if successful).
 */
@POST(PALINTIRI_SVC_PATH)
Response makePalintiri(@Query("numberOfPalintiri")  int numberOfPalantiri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example from android to servlet communication.

On your android do the following.

- Add retrofit dependency in the gradle.
- Add a Network Util class.

  ```
      public class NetworkUtil {

          public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
              OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
              okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(AppConstants.TIMEOUT_CONNECT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(AppConstants.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              okHttpClient.setWriteTimeout(AppConstants.READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                  .baseUrl(WebServiceConstant.WEBSERVICE_URL_PREFIX)
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                  .build();
             return retrofit;
         }

         public static EndPointInterface endPointInterface(){
              EndPointInterface endPointInterface = new NetworkUtil().getRetrofit().create(EndPointInterface.class);
              return endPointInterface;
         }
      }
  ```
- Set a request and response beans see this>
  http://square.github.io/retrofit/
- Call the end point which is the name of the servlet that you will set on your server side.

SERVER SIDE servlet

- just copy paste the doPOst method and make a third one name it as you like
- copy paste the beans from you android side to the server
- make and object of that bean e.g

  FriendsBean friendsBean = **new Gson().fromJson(res, FriendsBean.class);**
  friendsBean.getId()? or what ever you want from android side.
- Do you coding or play accordingly may be adding those values in dp or viceversa
- add this method to write the response back

  ```
  public static void writeServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response,String respStr){

          response.setContentType(Constants.RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE);

          PrintWriter writer = null;
          try {
              writer = response.getWriter();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          writer.println(respStr); 
  }
  ```

Hope it helps may be a little happy to give you more input in comments

Answer (score 0):

For servlets implementation of given API on server you don't have to implement you interface (because servlet processing method onPost/onGet signatures do not support returning values).

Just keep in mind that all API communication is based on underlying HTTP protocol.

Just be sure that server implementation return value in format that is expected by client.

```
 @Override
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {
    Long leaseDuration = Long.valueOf(req.getParameter("leaseDuration"));
    int result = ...;//some result of the method 
    resp.getWriter().println(result);
  }
```